# How to do I find the code calling a c# class method if the method is an operator?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, nullreferenceexception

I'm very new to c# and visual studio, so I don't know many of the techniques one would use to debug.

The code is triggering an exception on this method:

```
public static implicit operator T(RangeNode<T> node)
{
    return node.Value;
}
```

The "return node.Value;" area is highlighted with a NullReferenceException, and I can see that 'node' being passed in is null.

In order to fix it, I need to find the calling code and see why it's passing in null.

Normally in Visual Studio I can find this by clicking the "X references" helper above the function signature to see what calls it, but it doesn't appear for this operator method. Any ideas how I can find the calling code?

Comment: The call stack should still be available - run the code in debug, and View the call stack when it breaks on the NRE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When executing your program, put a breakpoint inside `public static implicit operator T(RangeNode<T> node)` and make sure you have the **Call Stack** window of Visual Studio:

[image: Visual Studio]

And look down to see this window:

[image: Call Stack Window]

Now, you can click on any of the method calls in the call stack, see who called this method and what parameters it passed to it.

Answer (score 2):

When you are running Visual Studio in Debug mode, your code will essentially pause execution when you hit an exception like you are. When this happens, you want to look at the call stack -- which is every function you are nested in, from the entry function (`Main` usually) all the way down to where you are in the operator. When you are here, you have the ability to traverse the call stack.

To make sure this is open, go to DEBUG > Windows > Call Stack. It will highlight this or open it, usually at the bottom of the screen. The function you are currently in when you broke on your exception will be at the top of the stack, and should have an arrow next to it. The function directly beneath it is the function where this operator was used. If you click on it, it will take you to the exact line where the operator was used.

Using the call stack to Debug is an incredibly useful tool!